# Minimum RAM for Email Server

Tags: email, server, vps, mail-server

I don't have much experience with servers and costs, so I was looking for suggestions about minimum RAM required on a VPS for an email server that receives emails 24/7, and only occasionally sends out email.

Around 5000 emails per day to many addresses/aliases, with each email being less than 200KB, and mostly without attachments.

The amount of mails grow over time, but right now I'm trying to keep costs as low as possible, and the numbers will stay under these for a while. Thanks!

Edit: I'm planning to use Postal, which requires Ubuntu 17.04 or above.

Comment: The operating system will require more RAM than the email application.  Find out what the operating system runs comfortably with.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Ubuntu 17.04 (min 2GB ram), or anything above. 4GB should be more than enough, right? Or do I need to take anything else into account? (I don't need to store emails on that server as I'm storing them somewhere else due of the platform I'm building)

Comment: 4GB should be sufficient.